# Let $(X, \tau)$ be Alexandrov topology, show that $f:X \rightarrow X$ is continuous iff

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, where $\tau$ is defined such as

$\tau = \{G \subseteq X: \forall x,y \in X \ (x\in G \ \land x \prec y) \Rightarrow y\in G\}$.

Show, that map $f:X \rightarrow X$ is continuous if and only if $(x \prec y \Rightarrow f(x) \prec f(x))$.

First implication $(\Rightarrow)$

Suppose, that $f:X \rightarrow X$ is continuous. From the definition of continuity, for every open set $U \subset X$ pre-image $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open in $X$. Since $U$ is open, for $f(x),f(y)\in U$ we receive that $f(x)\prec f(y)$. Moreover, from the fact that $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open, 
$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Same situation for $y \in f^{-1}(U)$.
So we get, that $x\prec y$.

Is it correct up till now?

I don't know how to show that the second implication is also true. Hint would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $\prec$ is a preorder on $X$. What you have so far is not correct, I’m afraid: $f(x),f(y)\in U$ does not imply that $f(x)\prec f(y)$. All you know is that if $f(x)\in U$ and $f(x)\prec y$, then $y\in U$.

To show the first implication, assume that $f$ is continuous, and let $x,y\in X$ be such that $x\prec y$; you need to show that $f(x)\prec f(y)$. Suppose that $f(x)\not\prec f(y)$, and let $U=\{z\in X:f(x)\prec z\}$.

- Show that $U$ is an open nbhd of $f(x)$ such that $f(y)\notin U$.
- Conclude that $f^{-1}[U]$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $y\notin f^{-1}[U]$.
- Get a contradiction by showing that $y$ is in every open nbhd of $x$.

Now assume that $f$ is order-preserving, and for each $x\in X$ let $B_x=\{y\in X:x\prec y\}$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_x:x\in X\}$.

- Show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $\tau$.
- Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Show that if $y\in f^{-1}[B_x]$ and $y\prec z$, then $z\in f^{-1}[B_x]$. Conclude that $f^{-1}[B_x]$ is open.
- Conclude that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I have proven first implication, but I have one question about what you've said about the basis. To prove, that $\mathscr B$ is a basis, we have to show that for an arbitrary open set $G$ it's a sum of some sets $B_{x}$, is it true to say that $G = \bigcup_{x\in G}B_{x}$ ?

Comment: @janusz: Yes: for each $x\in G$ we have $x\in B_x\subseteq G$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I suppose I'll do the rest. :)

Comment: @janusz: You’re welcome. Feel free to ask questions if you get stuck on any of it.